# Fusion charts, using session id in it

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

I am trying to show graph of the pic which is currently shown in my php based gallery.

In gallery page:

```
$_SESSION["frameid"] = $id_array[$i];
session_register("frameid");
```

In piedata.php, i code

```
session_start();
$frameid = $_SESSION["frameid"];
```

And then

```
$strQuery = "select * from vote_frames WHERE frame_id=$frameid 
             union 
             SELECT * FROM vote_frames WHERE frame_id!=$frameid LIMIT 0,3";
```

But it does not show any thing, looks like it is not picking up session value.

Comment: you are vulnerable to SQL injection possibly. session can be modified even though it is on the server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`session_register()`](http://php.net/session_register) is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 . You should just remove that line and it would pick it up.  Try either just

```
session_start();
// ...
$_SESSION["frameid"] = $id_array[$i];
```

or if you want to stick with `session_register()` do

```
session_start();
// ...
$frameid = $id_array[$i];
session_register("frameid");
```

Comment: Great did it! session_register() was problem.